# SQL 2005 Split Comma Separated Column on Delimiter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

My google searches on how to split a string on a delimiter have resulted in some useful functions for splitting strings when the string is known (i.e. see below):

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Split] (@String varchar(8000), @Delimiter char(1))     
   returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(8000))       
   as       
   begin       
       declare @idx int       
        declare @slice varchar(8000)       

        select @idx = 1       
            if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

       while @idx!= 0       
       begin       
           set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
           if @idx!=0       
               set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
           else       
              set @slice = @String       

           if(len(@slice)>0)  
               insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)       

           set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
           if len(@String) = 0 break       
       end   
   return       
   end
```

This works well for a known string like:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM dbo.Split('This,Is,My,List',',')
```

However, I would like to pass a column to a function, and have it unioned together with my other data in it's own row... for example given the data:

```
CommaColumn   ValueColumn1   ValueColumn2
-----------   ------------   -------------
ABC,123       1              2
XYZ, 789      2              3
```

I would like to write something like:

```
SELECT Split(CommaColumn,',') As SplitValue, ValueColumn1, ValueColumn2 FROM MyTable
```

And get back

```
SplitValue    ValueColumn1   ValueColumn2
----------    ------------   ------------
ABC           1              2
123           1              2
XYZ           2              3
789           2              3
```

Is this possible, or has anyone done this before?

Comment: 99% of the time or more comma seperated columns are a result of bad database design in the first place.  The only place for a split function on the server level is refactoring those columns into their own table.

Comment: I hope this table is from you staging database and contains raw data from a proprietary system where you have no way to change the table layout?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it's possible with CROSS APPLY (SQL 2005+):

```
with testdata (CommaColumn, ValueColumn1, ValueColumn2) as (
  select 'ABC,123', 1, 2 union all
  select 'XYZ, 789', 2, 3
  ) 
select 
  b.items as SplitValue
, a.ValueColumn1
, a.ValueColumn2
from testdata a
cross apply dbo.Split(a.CommaColumn,',') b
```

Notes:

1. You should add an index to the result set of your split column, so that it returns two columns, IndexNumber and Value.
2. In-line implementations with a numbers table are generally faster than your procedural version here.

eg:

```
create function [dbo].[Split] (@list nvarchar(max), @delimiter nchar(1) = N',')
returns table
as
return (
  select 
    Number = row_number() over (order by Number)
  , [Value] = ltrim(rtrim(convert(nvarchar(4000),
        substring(@list, Number
        , charindex(@delimiter, @list+@delimiter, Number)-Number
        )
    )))
  from dbo.Numbers
  where Number <= convert(int, len(@list))
    and substring(@delimiter + @list, Number, 1) = @delimiter
  )
```

Erland Sommarskog has the definitive page on this, I think: http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html

Comment: Excelent Peter. Saved my a** from a lot of trouble:)

Answer (score 10):

Fix it the right way--make that column a related table. No good ever comes of comma-separated scalar columns.

Comment: Unfortunately not my ideal situation, but still correct nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

+1 to the anti-CSV comments, but if you must do this you would use CROSS APPLY or OUTER APPLY.

Answer (score 1):

```
alter procedure [dbo].[usp_split](@strings varchar(max)) as  
begin  
    Declare @index int  
    set @index=1  
    declare @length int  
    set @length=len(@strings)  
    declare @str varchar(max)  
    declare @diff int  
    declare @Tags table(id varchar(30))  
    while(@index<@length)  
    begin  
        if(@index='1')  
        begin  
            set @str=(SELECT substring(@strings, @index, (charindex(',',(substring(@strings, @index,(@length)))))-1))  
            insert into @Tags values(@str)  
                set @index=(charindex(',',(substring(@strings, @index,(@length)))))  
        end  
        else  
        begin  
            set @diff=@length-@index  
            if(@diff !=0)  
            begin  
                set @str=(select substring(@strings, @index, (charindex(',',(substring(@strings,@index,@diff))))-1))  
                if(@str is not null and @str!='')  
                begin  
                    insert into @Tags VALUES(@str)  
                end  
                set @index=@index +(charindex(',',(substring(@strings, @index,@diff))))  
            end  
        end
    end
    set @str=(select right(@strings,(charindex(',',(substring(reverse(@strings),1,(@length)))))-1)) 
    insert into @Tags VALUES(@str)   
    select id from @Tags  
end
```

Usage:

```
exec usp_split '1212,21213,1,3,133,1313131,1,231313,5'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
SELECT s.Items AS SplitValue, ValueColumn1, ValueColumn2 
FROM MyTable, Split(CommaColumn,',') AS s
```

Comment: Tried this, which unfortunately did not work.. thank you for your attempt.