# SQL Split Comma Separated Column on Delimiter

Tags: c#, sql, split

Here is a split function, it can apply as `dbo.Split('sf,we,fs,we',',')`, when I change the string to column name it doesn't work, such as `dbo.Split(table.columnName,',')`.

```
Select * from dbo.Split('dirk@test.com','@')
```

is works but

```
Select * from dbo.Split((Select Email from Users),'@')
```

has an error message:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '('.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ','
```

The Function is here:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Split] (@String varchar(8000), @Delimiter char(1))     
   returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(8000))       
   as       
   begin       
       declare @idx int       
        declare @slice varchar(8000)       

        select @idx = 1       
            if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

       while @idx!= 0       
       begin       
           set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
           if @idx!=0       
               set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
           else       
              set @slice = @String       

           if(len(@slice)>0)  
               insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)       

           set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
           if len(@String) = 0 break       
       end   
   return       
   end
```

which it's refered to: [SQL 2005 Split Comma Separated Column on Delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951401/sql-2005-split-comma-separated-column-on-delimiter)

Or someone can give me a similiar function which can split one column into two

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the "it doesn't work" part?

Comment: The function operates on a varchar value, not on a column.  That value could come from a column, of course.

You are using this to normalize CSV data into the multiple columns it should have stored in from the beginning, right?

Answer (score 1):

That is because the function is returning a TABLE.

```
SELECT Split(myColumn) FROM myTable
```

will mean

```
SELECT myOutputTableFromSplit FROM myTable
```

It means, return a table from the table & SQL cannot do that.

Comment: No, I don't mean that, I have been use 
SELECT* FROM dbo.Split((Select top 1 Users.Email From Users),'@')

Comment: I just want to exactly the same result as the Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951401/sql-2005-split-comma-separated-column-on-delimiter       Thanks for your response

Comment: I also know it returns a table, and I also want to transfer this table's row to column