# 'Simple' SQL Search query

Tags: sql, sql-server, search

Ok, so I'm working on a basic search SPROC.
One of the Parameters is a search text (this will be the test the user enters in, words separated by spaces etc.)

Now all I need is to search these words on a single column in a table, BUT I want it to have ALL the keywords that were entered (at the moment all I can do is if 1 of them is there)

So is there a special SQL command that allows me to do this?

Comment: The problem with those 2 answers is the search terms are always going to be different. I can spilt the words up into a table but then im still not too sure how to search all of them because i can do an IN on that table but thats still the same problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this

check the occurances of the words required, and compare to the count of split words.

All issue i forsee is matches to partial words, but this might get you started

```
/*
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString]
(
        @String VARCHAR(8000) ,
        @Delimiter  VARCHAR(10)
)
RETURNS @RetTable TABLE(
        String varchar(1000)
)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @i INT ,
            @j INT
    SELECT  @i = 1
    WHILE @i <= LEN(@String)
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @j = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String, @i)
        IF @j = 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT  @j = LEN(@String) + 1
        END
        INSERT  @RetTable SELECT SUBSTRING(@String, @i, @j - @i)
        SELECT  @i = @j + LEN(@Delimiter)
    END
    RETURN
END
*/

DECLARE @SearchString VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SearchString = 'your,of'

DECLARE @SearchStringTable TABLE(
        Words VARCHAR(MAX)
)

DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(
        Col VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @TABLE (Col)
SELECT 
'On the Insert tab, the galleries include items that are designed to coordinate with the overall look of your document.'
INSERT INTO @TABLE (Col)
SELECT 
'You can use these galleries to insert tables, headers, footers, lists, cover pages, and other document building blocks.'
INSERT INTO @TABLE (Col)
SELECT 
'When you create pictures, charts, or diagrams, they also coordinate with your current document look.'

INSERT INTO @SearchStringTable (Words) SELECT * FROM dbo.SplitString(@SearchString,',')

SELECT  t.Col,
        COUNT(1) AS Number
FROM    @TABLE t,
        @SearchStringTable s
WHERE   CHARINDEX(s.Words,t.Col) > 0
GROUP BY t.Col
HAVING  COUNT(1) = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM @SearchStringTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the @SEARCH_TEXT into the words and ideally store it in a temporary table @FILTER_TABLE with one column WORD containing the words. You can google for "sql comma split ...", but answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273552/sql-split-comma-separated-column-on-delimiter) might be helpful. [This](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=50648) is also interesting.

Then you just use JOIN in your query to filter the rows. The simplest query then that would return all the matches would be:

```
SELECT  t.*
        f.WORD
FROM    MyTable t
JOIN    @FILTER_TABLE f
    ON t.MyColumn = f.WORD --// = or LIKE operator
```

But if you provide an example of your data and expected result, people would could be more helpful.