# Separately comma delimited column into unique column

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a table:

```
 ID      name
 1       john, peter, ken
```

how can i separate the name column (which the value are being separated with comma delimited) into separate column using MYSQL?

```
ID       name
1        john
1        peter
1        ken
```

Comment: Why the C# tag? This has nothing to do with C#.

Comment: This question has been asked a million times here on SO.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Convert Comma Seperated Column into rows and add counter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184529/how-to-convert-comma-seperated-column-into-rows-and-add-counter) or here with C# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273552/sql-split-comma-separated-column-on-delimiter?rq=1

Comment: well i just found the answer like you have requested. Check the link http://www.marcogoncalves.com/2011/03/mysql-split-column-string-into-rows/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a query like this:

```
SELECT
  id,
  n.digit,
  name,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ',', n.digit+1), ',', -1)
FROM
  mytable
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT 0 digit UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) n
  ON LENGTH(REPLACE(name, ',' , '')) <= LENGTH(name)-n.digit
```

(please notice that this will only separate up to 4 names).

Fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44c60/1).

**Explanation**

I'm making use of a query that returns all numbers from 0 to 3 (you could use an indexed table with 10 or 100 numbers, for example):

```
SELECT 0 digit UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3
```

I'm then joining this number with `mytable`, using this join conditions:

```
ON LENGTH(REPLACE(name, ',' , '')) <= LENGTH(name)-n.digit
```

which is a "dirty" way to check if the name column contains at least `n.digit` names (I'm removing all commas, and I'm checking the difference in length with the full string).

Using SUBSTRING_INDEX you can get the part of the string at the left of the `n.digit+1` comma:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ',', n.digit+1)
```

and using one more SUBSTRING_INDEX with a negative parameter you can only keep the part of the string up to the first comma:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ',', n.digit+1), ',', -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get thh data into mysql then you can create a php file using explode to create an array per id.

These may help:

[How can I split a comma delimited string into an array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125730/how-can-i-split-a-comma-delimited-string-into-an-array-in-php)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php