# how to do whole word search in multi keywords string

Tags: sql-server, search

Need help for search multi keywords:

For 2 keywords string: `img_keywords(1)="error bar, cloumn"`, `img_keywords(2)="bar, graph"`, how to search "bar, abc", just return the second string?

Tried `SELECT * FROM images WHERE CONTAINS(img_KeyWords, '"bar" OR "abc" ' )`, return both strings. But, should just be the second one match.

Comment: what about using LIKE instead of HAVING. Which SQL Server RDBMS are you using. Can you update your question with some sample data.

Answer (score 1):

I asked a similar question in the past ([SQL 2005 Split Comma Separated Column on Delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951401/sql-2005-split-comma-separated-column-on-delimiter)).  Honestly, you shouldn't store csv data in scalar columns.  There isn't a performance efficient way to manage that.

If you were to split those values into a relational table, it would solve your query issue.